# Assertion crashing my program even if condition is true

Tags: c, assert

I have a function where I assert (using assert.h) that a passed argument is greater than 0:

```
DynArr* createDynArr(int cap)
{
    assert(cap > 0);
    ...
}
```

when this line runs in main..

```
DynArr *dyn;
dyn = createDynArr(2);
```

I get this error:

```
main: dynamicArray.c:46: createDynArr: Assertion 'cap > 0' failed.
Abort(core dumped)
```

why is it doing this?

edit - here is a more complete example.

This is the struct and the full implementation of the function in file dynamicArray.c:

```
struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
    int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
    int capacity;   /* capacity ofthe array */
};

DynArr* createDynArr(int cap)
{
    assert(cap > 0);
    DynArr *r = (DynArr *)malloc(sizeof( DynArr));
    assert(r != 0);
    initDynArr(r,cap);
    return r;
}

void initDynArr(DynArr *v, int capacity)
{
    assert(capacity > 0);
    assert(v!= 0);
    v->data = (TYPE *) malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * capacity);
    assert(v->data != 0);
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = capacity;
}
```

In a separate file, testDynArr.c, I have main function in which I try to create a DynArr struct and give it capacity of 2:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    DynArr *dyn;
    dyn = createDynArr(2);

    printf("\n\nTesting addDynArr...\n");


  ...
}
```

I link these files like so:

```
gcc -o main dynamicArray.c testDynArr.c
```

and then run main which gives the assert error.

Comment: Please show [a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can try compile and execute.  Do reduce it to the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the error, though.  The above snippet doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Are you sure it's that line, and not some other `createDynArr` call?

Comment: so what's the value in `cap` at that point?

Comment: If you're sure that `cap` has an int value, try to do a cast to int inside the assert.

Comment: @BtcSources What would be the point of doing this?

Comment: @5gon12eder since we don't know why the assertion has failed, just try to figure out if the problem has something to do with the type of value being valued inside the expression.

Comment: @5gon12eder I added more details. very odd.

Comment: @user2357112 That is the only time I call createDynArr in main sadly

Comment: compiles and runs fine for me http://ideone.com/k9JB06

Comment: Same here, just worked fine. Compiled with: `gcc version 4.6.3`.

Comment: Your example is still incomplete and insufficient to provide useful help.  Please read through the help page linked in my previous comment and improve your question accordingly.  The error is very likely in a part of your program where you don't expect it but we can only tell you if we can see it.  The most likely thing to happen is that while you are trying to create the minimal example, the error will suddenly go away.  Congratulations: you have found the error yourself; it was on the last line you have deleted before that.  You might also find it helpful to run your program in a debugger.

Comment: run it under a debugger - you are not running the code you think you are, the debugger will show you what code you are actually running

Answer (score 0):

I see the only reason that you are using a value that when placed in an object of type int becomes a negative value. That is it seems that you are using an integer value that is greater than `INT_MAX`

As for your code snippet if to update some details (as for example using structure tag and so on) then it will compile and run successfully.

You should look at the assert message. It shows what is the actual value of cap.:)

Comment: Since this is `c` and type is `int`, this isn't an object but a primitive type. Having said that, shouldn't just return "false" (then, 0 as int value) the logic expression evaluation?

Comment: @Btc Sources I am sorry I have not understood what you said.

Comment: He could also have a stack corruption.

Comment: @5gon12eder  More likely that he uses an expression where int is converted to unsigned int (or size_t) and then when the function is called the value again is converted to int and becomes negative.